# How do I create a function that allows for user input to have a different outcomes based on how many times the same input was entered in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-input

I am creating a text based adventure game in Python.  At certain points there may be rooms with many different actions you can perform, like opening a chest.  I want to create a single function that allows this, because right now I have to write all this: 
(Just an example)

```
hello_said_once = True  

hello = ["hello", "hi"]
goodbye = ["goodbye", "bye", "cya"]

while True:

    user_input = raw_input("Hello... ")

    if any(i in user_input for i in hello) and hello_said_once:
        print "You said hello!"
    elif any(i in user_input for i in hello) and not hello_said_once:
        print "You already said Hello!"
    elif any(i in user_input for i in goodbye) and good_bye_said_once:
        print "You said Goodbye!"
        break
```

This gets tiresome after a while and I wouldn't know how to make a function for it, specifically because the amount of actions you could perform depends on the situation.

Comment: What about a dictionary indexed by the word and containing the number of uses?

Comment: @dlask That is a good idea.  How would I get the function to change depending on the amount of possible actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be worth using a `class` if you want to keep the function and usage count closely tied. A class can have persistent data so you could track the number of times the user called it by just increasing the number every time.

```
class chest():
    openCount = 0
    openFunctions = [
                        function1,
                        function2,
                        function3,
                        ...
                    ]

    def use(self):
        self.openFunctions[openCount]
        self.openCount += 1
```

You could use this to track other more dynamic data too, like a list of items received from chests.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably make a class that holds a list of valid inputs and a bool for whether or not it's been triggered yet.

```
class Action:
    def __init__(self, user_inputs):
        self.user_inputs = user_inputs
        self.been_triggered = False

hello = Action(["hello", "hi"])
goodbye = Action(["goodbye", "bye", "cya"])
```

Also, your use of "any" is redundant. You can just say `if user_input in hello and ...`

```
class Action:
    def __init__(self, user_inputs):
        self.user_inputs = user_inputs
        self.been_triggered = False

hello = Action(["hello", "hi"])
goodbye = Action(["goodbye", "bye", "cya"])

while True:

    user_input = raw_input("Hello... ")

    if user_input in hello.user_inputs:
        if not hello.been_triggered:
            print "You said hello!"
        else:
            print "You already said Hello!"

    elif user_input in goodbye.user_inputs:
        print "You said Goodbye!"
        break
```

Comment: This would be more efficient with e.g. `self.user_inputs = set(user_inputs)`

Comment: Any allows the user to input a full sentence doesn't it?

Comment: @conyare yes, but then how do you handle e.g. `'say hello goodbye'`?

Comment: @conyare sort of. I didn't realize you wanted to accept a full sentence for input. Although jonrsharpe does have a good point.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah I thought about that too.  Idk yet

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: @conyare It depends on what your desired outcome when the user enters something like that is. Should the program obey the first valid command? Obey both? Neither?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Hmm.  I'd probably want to change it depending on the situation.  So I'd probably use multiple of them.

Comment: @conyare Then you're probably going to want to write it so that it reads all  of the valid commands out of the input (probably into a list) and then uses some logic to determine which command it needs to follow.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Ok, I'll figure it out